# Why doesn't my WpfApp1.exe work correctly in unit test project's bin folder

Tags: c#, .net-core

Given:
.Net Core 3.1 WPF project
.Net Core 3.1 MSTest project (references WPF project for Appium purposes)

When I try to execute the WpfApp1.exe in my unit test project's bin folder it prompts me saying I have to install .Net Core. However, WpfApp1.exe works fine that's inside WpfApp1 project bin.  Not sure what's going on here.

[Here's a link to my repo](https://dev.azure.com/rodsandev01/HappeningsInDotnetCoreProject/_git/TestRepo1?path=%2FREADME.md&_a=preview)

[image]

Comment: It seems, that unit test project doesn't copy all dependencies for wpf app

Comment: but if you add a reference to it shouldn't it get all of it's dependencies?